# Sorting a generic linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, nodes

I have a problem with sorting generic linked lists. I have a function that
receives a linked list and a sorting criteria and sorts according to it.
I print the list right before the function ends and it is sorted accurately. However, when I print it right after the function has finished, the list is unsorted again, with an exception of the first node that is actually at the right place (The node that is supposed to be first is really put at the first place), but after it the rest of the list is sorted in the opposite order.

For example, the original list is 6,7,5,4,3,2. At the end of the function
the list is 2,3,4,5,6,7 but after the sorting function ends the list is 2,7,6,5,4,3.
I have tried a lot of methods (Bubble sort,Max sort,etc.) and they all give the same result that i described. Does anyone have a clue of what could be the problem?

here is my code -

```
ListResult listBubble(Node start,CompareListElements compare,CopyListElement copy){
    Node iterator=start,last=NULL;
    bool swapped=true;
    while(swapped){
        swapped=false;
        iterator=start;
        while(iterator->next!=last){
            if(compare(iterator->info,iterator->next->info)>0){
                printf("to swap: %s and %s\n",(char*)iterator->info,(char*)iterator->next->info);
                if(swapNodes(&iterator,&(iterator->next),copy)!=LIST_SUCCESS){
                    return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
                }
                swapped=true;
            }
            iterator=iterator->next;
        }
        last=iterator;
    }
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}


/*The "problematic" function*/
ListResult listSort(List list,CompareListElements compareElement){
    RESULT_NULL_CHECK(list)//Checking the list is valid
    RESULT_NULL_CHECK(compareElement)//Checking the camparing function is valid
    if(listGetSize(list)<=1){
        return LIST_SUCCESS;
    }//Nothing to sort if only one node
ListResult el=listBubble(list->head,compareElement,list->copyFunction);
/*A printing of the list comes here*/
return el;
}


//Calling the function:
ASSERT_TEST(listSort(list,string_compare)==LIST_SUCCESS);

// *edit* code of swapNodes
static ListResult swapNodes(Node* node1,Node* node2, CopyListElement copy){
    ListElement temp=copy((*node1)->info);
    MEMORY_NULL_CHECK(temp)//checking if there was no memory allocation problem
    (*node1)->info=copy((*node2)->info);
    MEMORY_NULL_CHECK((*node1)->info)
    (*node2)->info=copy(temp);
    MEMORY_NULL_CHECK((*node2)->info)
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `swapNodes(&iterator,&(iterator->next),copy)` : this can't swap node. change to swap value(`info`).

Comment: The function does swap the info value. I added it's code to the message. Could there be something else?

Comment: Add Node element structure( `*iterator`), `copy` function... You provide code to Compile, Execute and   possible reproducible.